# Best way to copy enumerable own properties from an array of objects to anothers array of class objects

Tags: javascript

Lets say that i have this array of objects  :

```
 let x = [{Id:1,Name:"abc",Age:""},{Id:2,Name:"def",Age:""}] ;
```

How can i copy all its objects to an array of class objects without looping through all the elements and pushing them into new array something like this :

```
class ClientModel
 {

      constructor(){
        this.Id = null ; 
        this.Name = null ; 
      }
      
}


let x = [{Id:1,Name:"abc",Age:""},{Id:2,Name:"def",Age:""}] ; 
let y = new Array() ; 

x.forEach(elem =>y.push(Object.assign(new ClientModel(),elem)));
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `copy all its objects to an array of class objects`?

Comment: How do you _"copy all its objects ... without looping through all the elements"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a meaningful constructor for `ClientModel` and `map` the data array like this:

```
class ClientModel {
    constructor(data) {
        this.Id = data.Id;
        this.Name = data.Name;
    }
}

let array = [{Id: 1, Name: "abc", Age: ""}, ....
let objects = array.map(d => new ClientModel(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you need to loop the original array, but just use `map` and object deconstruction to make life easier.

```js
let x = [{Id:1,Name:"abc",Age:""},{Id:2,Name:"def",Age:""}] ; 

class ClientModel
 {

      constructor(id, name){
        this.Id = id ; 
        this.Name = name ; 
      }
      
}

let y = x.map(({Id,Name}) => new ClientModel(Id,Name))
console.log(y);
```